# Autopopulate Excel invoice using vlookup

Tags: excel

I'd like to auto-populate an invoice in Excel from data I enter into a lesson roster (`blank_monthly.xlsx`).

[image]

Here I fill in the lesson cost under the date each time they come for tuition.

In the invoice sheet I would like to start writing a customer's name into a cell, I'd like the rest of the table to populate with information from the current month's customer roster.

Can I use `=vlookup` for this to reference the cell I type the client's name into which then pulls all the other information?

Comment: Does the Student Name column in your screen shot contain multiple names? Will the names be split, in the other sheet? ie `Zoe`,`Pete`,`Lucy`,`James` all in separate cells, or all in the same cell?

Comment: The names are in one cell and stay together.

Comment: Ah. I've just posted my answer before I saw your comment. I accounted for both situations, just in case.

Answer (score 1):

If your names are split on the invoice sheet, but not the lesson plan, then you can use `VLOOKUP` with wildcards as below

Lesson Plan sheet
[image: Lesson Plan Sheet]

Invoice sheet

[image: Invoice Sheet]

`*` in the VLOOKUP function will match any characters.

```
=VLOOKUP("*"&$A2&"*",Sheet2!$A$2:$G$4,2,FALSE)
```

If your names aren't split then you can just omit the wildcard search, as below.

[image: Invoice Sheet 2]

```
=VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$G$4,2,FALSE)
```

Currently if no matches are found then the function will return 0. If you just want a blank cell, then you can nest the function in an `IF`

```
=IF(VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$G$4,2,FALSE)=0,"",VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$G$4,2,FALSE))
```

`VLOOKUP` documentation is [HERE](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx). You should read up on it.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your data sheet will contain 3 columns like: name, date of lesson and number of lessons.  You then want to produce a nice report that your illustrated. The short answer is 'Yes', you can use `VLOOKUP` provided that you only have one row in your datasheet per person per day and you have a column with the concatenation of Name and date. Otherwise, you have to use `SUMIFS`. I recommend `SUMIFS` because it would be cleaner formula.

The name is easy to match. Date should handle itself, as long as you don't try to control Excel's magic. Date is stored as a number. The cell formatting makes it look like a date. Concatenate your Month, Day, Year to the proper format and use the `DATEVALUE` function.

If you have your anchors (`$`) correct, you should be able to copy and paste the formula. If you don't want to see 0s on your summary report, don't `IF` in the formula, control it using cell formatting - custom `0;;`.

If you are familiar with `Table` vs `Range`, use table. Your formula will look nicer and you don't have to worry about extending your range as you acquire more lessons.

Comment: This seems like what I'm looking for, my problem is that the blank_monthly is remade every month. Ie for November, I have November.xlsx. Is there any way of making the formula in the invoice sheet update with the month I specify in some cell?

Comment: Sure. DATEVALUE should recognize 'November'. Research "Data Validation" then evaluate if you really need separate sheet every month.